# Why comparing float values is such difficult?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compare

I am newbie in Unity platform. I have 2D game that contains 10 boxes vertically following each other in chain. When a box goes off screen, I change its position to above of the box at the top. So the chain turns infinitely, like repeating Parallax Scrolling Background.

But I check if a box goes off screen by comparing its position with a specified float value. I am sharing my code below.

```
void Update () {
    offSet = currentSquareLine.transform.position;
    currentSquareLine.transform.position = new Vector2 (0f, -2f) + offSet;

    Vector2 vectorOne = currentSquareLine.transform.position;
    Vector2 vectorTwo = new Vector2 (0f, -54f);

    if(vectorOne.y < vectorTwo.y) {
        string name = currentSquareLine.name;
        int squareLineNumber = int.Parse(name.Substring (11)) ;
        if(squareLineNumber < 10) {
            squareLineNumber++;
        } else {
            squareLineNumber = 1;
        }
        GameObject squareLineAbove = GameObject.Find ("Square_Line" + squareLineNumber);

        offSet = (Vector2) squareLineAbove.transform.position + new Vector2(0f, 1.1f);
        currentSquareLine.transform.position = offSet;
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I compare vectorOne.y and vectorTwo.y, things get ugly. Some boxes lengthen and some boxes shorten the distance between each other even I give the exact vector values in the code above.

I've searched for a solution for a week, and tried lots of codes like Mathf.Approximate, Mathf.Round, but none of them managed to compare float values properly. If unity never compares float values in the way I expect, I think I need to change my way.

I am waiting for your godlike advices, thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my screen. I have 10 box lines vertically goes downwards.

[image: Screen Structure]

When Square_Line10 goes off screen. I update its position to above of Square_Line1, but the distance between them increases unexpectedly.

Comment: I don't think floating point comparison is your problem, it seems like a logic error. Can you simplify your scene structure to isolate the problem?

Comment: I edited the post by adding a screenshot showing my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution that works like a charm.

I need to use an array and check them in two for loops. First one moves the boxes and second one check if a box went off screen like below

```
public GameObject[] box;
float boundary = -5.5f;
float boxDistance = 1.1f;
float speed = -0.1f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    for (int i = 0; i < box.Length; i++) {
        box[i].transform.position = box[i].transform.position + new Vector3(0, speed, 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < box.Length; i++)
    {
        if(box[i].transform.position.y < boundary)
        {
            int topIndex = (i+1) % box.Length;

            box[i].transform.position = new Vector3(box[i].transform.position.x, box[topIndex].transform.position.y + boxDistance, box[i].transform.position.z);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I attached it to MainCamera.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
bool IsApproximately(float a, float b, float tolerance = 0.01f) {
    return Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance;
}
```

The reason being that the tolerances in the internal compare aren't good to use. Change the tolerance value in a function call to be lower if you need more precision.

Comment: The OP stated that they already tried the Mathf.Approximately method. Also, he is comparing with less-than, not equality test, so I don't think this is the issue.